# Eventlistener for input not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to call keyup event using ***EventListener*** for **input tag** but it is not working and I don't know why. below is my code

```js
document.getElementById("ajax").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  alert("called");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="e.g. datalist">
<datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
```

Even if I tried ***JQuery*** but still it is not working but if I use

```
document.addEventListener(keyup,function(){
      alert("called");
    });)
```

then this is working but this is not what I want 
Help will be appriciated

Comment: Your code is working.

Comment: Do you want it in jquery?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your **JavaScript** Code is working

Try Following Using Jquery

```js
$('#ajax').keypress(function(){
alert('called')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="e.g. datalist">
<datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
```

You can Try Using `jquery` **Keyup** Event

```js
$(document).on('keyup','#ajax',function(){
alert('Called');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="e.g. datalist">
<datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$("#ajax").keyup(function() {
      alert( "called" )
 })
```

or

```
$("#ajax").on( "keyup", function() {
   alert( "called" )
})
```